# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups' in Regex

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written a regex to scrape the data from the web page. However I am getting the mentioned error. I am not able to find a solution to that.
Someone had suggested

```
try:
    code
except:
     Attribute error
```

Original Code:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4
import re

url ='https://ipinfo.io/AS7018'
def url_to_soup(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    html = opener.open(req)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    return soup


s = str(url_to_soup(url))
#print(s)
asn_code, name = re.search(r'<h3 class="font-semibold m-0 t-xs-24">(?P<ASN_CODE>AS\d+) (?P<NAME>[\w.\s]+)</h3>', s)\
        .groups() # Error code
print(asn_code)
""" This is where the error : From above code """
country = re.search(r'.*href="/countries.*">(?P<COUNTRY>.*)?</a>',s).group("COUNTRY")
print(country)
registry = re.search(r'Registry.*?pb-md-1">(?P<REGISTRY>.*?)</p>',s, re.S).group("REGISTRY").strip()
print(registry)
# flag re.S make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline;
ip = re.search(r'IP Addresses.*?pb-md-1">(?P<IP>.*?)</p>',s, re.S).group("IP").strip()
print(ip)
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

`re.search(r'<h3 class="font-semibold m-0 t-xs-24">(?P<ASN_CODE>AS\d+) (?P<NAME>[\w.\s]+)</h3>', s)`

is returning `None` the pattern you're looking for has not being found in the string `s`.

According to documentation for `re.search`

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return **None** if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

You have to redesign your regex or debug your code in order to find out what `s` contains by the time the mentioned pattern is used.

Answer (score 1):

`re.search` returns `None` when it fails to find anything. `None` does not respond to the method `.groups()`. Check whether a match exists or not before you inspect the match in detail.

```
match = re.search(r'<h3 class="font-semibold m-0 t-xs-24">(?P<ASN_CODE>AS\d+) (?P<NAME>[\w.\s]+)</h3>', s)
if match:
    asn_code, name = match.groups()
```

However, since you're using Beautiful Soup, why stringify and then regex match? It's like buying a packet of instant soup, adding the powder to the water, boiling the thing, then *dehydrating it back to powder*. Why even use BeautifulSoup then?

```
soup.select('h3.font-semibold.m-0.t-xs-24')[0].content
```

will give you the content of that `<h3>` element; then apply regex on *that*, if you need to. Regexping through HTML documents is [generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

**EDIT**: What exactly gives you `TypeError`? This is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you're solving the wrong thing. I verified this to work, with no `TypeError` (Python 3):

```
ast_re = re.compile(r'(?P<ASN_CODE>AS\d+) (?P<NAME>[\w.\s]+)')
soup = url_to_soup(url)
ast_h3 = next(
    (m for m in (ast_re.match(h3.text) for h3 in soup.select('h3')) if m),
    None)
if ast_h3:
    asn_code, name = asn_h3.groups()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works partly, because I guess some issue with regex which Im not able to fix. However let me try and answer the second part i why I am stringfying bs4, its becuase it gives me "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" error. In any case can you pls help with the regex to match. I believe when there is &amp in line the regex is rejecting it. Which I am trying to overcome.